# resque-status is not compatible with my current resque version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I added a new gem to my `Gemfile` unrelated to the `resque` gem and I've having issues with `bundle install`. I do not want to run bundle update because I don't wan't to make unnecessary changes within the `Gemfile.lock`. What is the best way to get past this error without making too many changes? I want to keep my resque versions consistent with previous versions.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "resque":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    resque (= 2.0.0)

  In Gemfile:
    resque (~> 2.0.0)

    resque-status was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
      resque (~> 1.19)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Comment: `bundle update {gem_name} --conservative` will just update the gem(s) you want https://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html.

Comment: What gem unrelated to the `resque` gem did you add?

Comment: Thanks @dbugger! Worked out well for me when I ran bundle update resque-status --conservative

Comment: @spickermann it was just a custom gem with a code snippet.

Comment: I am very surprised that adding a new gem unrelated to `resque` and `resque-status` leads to a `could not find compatible versions` error on `resque` and `resque-status`.

Comment: @spickermann I am betting the OP added `resque-status` as this is the dependency issue. OP I would recommend looking elsewhere for the funtionality provided by `resque-status` as you will not be able to solve that dependency issue without making too many changes. Also you will be dropping back a full major version of an actively developed gem to utilize an abandoned one. (`resque-status` has not been updated in 6 years)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `resque-status`: its last commit (to date, for 0.5.0 version) was done [5 years ago](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/commits), so is a pretty outdated and unmaintained gem.
As long as this isn't updated, you should try luck with some of the forks. [This looks promising](https://github.com/fishisfast/resque-status), as it update the version restrictions [in the gemspec](https://github.com/fishisfast/resque-status/commit/8d1701496e4b484fdae9ac3bc884cb71703aecba), so try adding to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'resque-status', git: 'https://github.com/fishisfast/resque-status.git', branch: :master
```

Another solution is trying with another gem, like [resque-web](https://github.com/resque/resque-web), which looks "a bit" more maintained, but I don't promise anything.